# how to display a smoothbox popup on onclick of a link, which is loaded through Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

I have implemented a smoothbox popup

Following the code

```
<a href="test.php" class="smoothbox">read</a>
```

While clicking this link, the test.php page will display in popup.Its working for me.

Now i have a section, where this link is loaded  through ajax (exact same  link).

But the popup is not working, while clicking the link, its just redirecting to test.php.

Can any one tell a solution for this

Comment: How are you opening that popup?

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the code.

You can make something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="smoothbox">read</a>
```

or you can also use ID:

```
<a id="smoothbox">read</a>
```

You should handle the $('smoothbox').click(function{}); in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But can you little more explain it

Comment: Iam getting the popup, while i use it in the link as static.But if i  load the same link through ajax,then the smoothbox popup  is not working

Comment: Actually i just loading the link<a href="test.php" class="smoothbox">read</a> in a div with jquery load function.Then try to click and open the link in popup.But not working

Comment: If you don't have the code - how do you do it then? Whatever code you have. Please put them on jsfiddle and share the link